# Best solution to cache objects and images on Android?

Tags: android, caching, storage

What is the preferred way of caching different objects (including images) on Android? My goal is to cache some data for quick access, and to keep them available for longer time (for days). 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a disk cache. Jack Wharton's DiskLruCache is very good https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache.

It will save what you want to disk and read from it, and you can build around it to set max-age values for cache.

Answer (score 1):

use Volley for the better caching of images and objects. Its a faster library for android to load data from web.
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10789157)

Comment: @From Review . The question is in closed status so i dont think its good to edit the answer here